# How to create dynamic task mapping for postgres operator in airflow?

Tags: airflow, postgres-operator

I am completely new to AirFlow and I am trying to create 8 tasks which are pretty simillar.

I've read about expand() methond though I am not quite sure how to use it for PostgresOperator?

So I have this task:

```
t1 = PostgresOperator(
task_id='load_something_1',
postgres_conn_id="postgres_default",
sql = "SELECT somefunction_1()", 
dag=dag)
```

I need to create similar tasks only they gotta have **load_something_2**, **load_something_3** etc. and
**SELECT somefucntion_2**, **SELECT somefucntion_3** etc.

How do I do this  using dynamic task mapping ?

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say whether you need `expand()` or not without knowing what your iterator looks like, and how the data is made available to the DAG, but here's how this could be accomplished with a simple iterator in a full-example DAG:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
from airflow.decorators import dag, task

@dag(
    default_args={
        'owner': 'me'
    },
    dag_id=f'example-dag',
    start_date=datetime(2023,1,6),
    schedule_interval=None,
)
def workflow():

    @task
    def load_something(i):
        t1 = PostgresOperator(
            task_id=f'load_something',
            postgres_conn_id="postgres_default",
            sql = f"SELECT somefunction_{i}()",
        )
    my_tasks = [load_something(i) for i in range(1,9)]
    # my_tasks = [load_something.override(task_id=f'load_something_{i+1}')(i) for i in range(1,9)]
    my_tasks
workflow()
```

**Note**: just calling your task like `my_tasks = [load_something(i) for i in range(1,9)]` with the @task decorator will automatically enumerate your task names for you:[image] if you want to explicitly name the tasks, you can do so using the `override()` method. Uncomment out `my_tasks = [load_something.override(task_id=f'load_something_{i}')(i) for i in range(1,9)]`:
[image]